# How to show a flow document using a DocumentViewer?

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument, documentviewer

I have a simple flow document in my resources, `FlowDocument1.xaml`:

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          ColumnWidth="400" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia">
    <Paragraph>
        Test
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

And I want to show this document in a `DocumentViewer`. I searched for a property that takes path but I couldn't find one. And the following throws an exception:

```
<DocumentViewer x:Name="TestViewer" Document="Resources/FlowDocument1.xaml" />
```

How can I show `FlowDocument1.xaml` in a `DocumentViewer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you cannot add a `FlowDocument` to a `DocumentViewer` because it only supports `FixedDocument`. You may use `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` or `FlowDocumentPageViewer` instead.

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer x:Name="TestViewer"/>
```

Then you have to set the `Document` property in code:

```
TestViewer.Document = Application.LoadComponent(
    new Uri("/Resources/FlowDocument1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as FlowDocument;
```

Comment: You may of course put the document in a resource dictionary and then access it as static resource.

Answer (score 5):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <FlowDocument x:Key="YourFlowDoc">
            <Paragraph>
                <TextBox Text="See it's Easy!"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <FlowDocumentReader Document="{StaticResource YourFlowDoc}" />
</Grid>
```