# How to Fill Data on a Table C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i'd like to create a table and fill it with my datas (it's supposed to look like cards than a datagrid)

I've copy paste microsoft doc but my table is not printed on the Main window. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-build-a-table-programmatically?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

(i usually use winform, thats why i'm lost)

here is my code :

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // instantiation de Data (qui contient les ExoBatt)
            DataExo Data = new DataExo();

            // Create the parent FlowDocument...
            FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();

            // Create the Table...
            Table table1 = new Table();
            // ...and add it to the FlowDocument Blocks collection.
            flowDoc.Blocks.Add(table1);

            // Set some global formatting properties for the table.
            table1.CellSpacing = 10;
            table1.Background = Brushes.White;
            // Create 6 columns and add them to the table's Columns collection.
            int numberOfColumns = 6;
            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfColumns; x++)
            {
                table1.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());

                // Set alternating background colors for the middle colums.
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                    table1.Columns[x].Background = Brushes.Beige;
                else
                    table1.Columns[x].Background = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            // Create and add an empty TableRowGroup to hold the table's Rows.
            table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());

            // Add the first (title) row.
            table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());

            // Alias the current working row for easy reference.
            TableRow currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];

            // Global formatting for the title row.
            currentRow.Background = Brushes.Silver;
            currentRow.FontSize = 40;
            currentRow.FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold;

            // Add the header row with content,
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("2004 Sales Project"))));
            // and set the row to span all 6 columns.
            currentRow.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 6;

            // Add the second (header) row.
            table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[1];

            // Global formatting for the header row.
            currentRow.FontSize = 18;
            currentRow.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

            // Add cells with content to the second row.
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Product"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Quarter 1"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Quarter 2"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Quarter 3"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Quarter 4"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("TOTAL"))));

            // Add the third row.
            table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[2];

            // Global formatting for the row.
            currentRow.FontSize = 12;
            currentRow.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

            // Add cells with content to the third row.
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Widgets"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("$50,000"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("$55,000"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("$60,000"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("$65,000"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("$230,000"))));

            // Bold the first cell.
            currentRow.Cells[0].FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[3];

            // Global formatting for the footer row.
            currentRow.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            currentRow.FontSize = 18;
            currentRow.FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.Normal;

            // Add the header row with content,
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Projected 2004 Revenue: $810,000"))));
            // and set the row to span all 6 columns.
            currentRow.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 6;

        }
```

Thank you !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17995533/1506454

Comment: @ASh I dont see the thing, i dont want to show any document my datas are in an object, used like this : `Data.GetExoBatterie()[x].id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `Content` of the window to a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` that displays your `FlowDocument`:

```
Content = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer() { Document = flowDoc  };
```

Then you should see the document.

The other option is to create the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` in the XAML markup of `MainWindow.xaml` and set the `Document` property of this instance:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer x:Name="fdsv" />
```

---

```
...
fdsv.Document = flowDoc;
```